# YouTube only plays audio in WebView

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview

https://drive.google.com/open?id=12rzhjzYvWTKGIQhlhP5OSCINhOAWCU73I want to show audio and video from YouTube using a Web View in Android, but on my mobile device I have a black screen while the video is playing. Audio is playing normally.

I give you two codes, one code that successfully displays audio and video (code 1). the second code (code 2) only successfully displays audio. why this happened? even though there isn't any change just the source of the different you_tube pages

code 1 :

```
package inducesmile.com.playvideoinandroid;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MyWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = null;
    private View mCustomView;
    private RelativeLayout mContentView;
    private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://murid.gkdi.org/test/out.html");
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }
            mContentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
            mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewContainer = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
            mCustomViewContainer.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
            mCustomViewContainer.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
            view.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
            mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
            mCustomView = view;
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1)
        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            if (mCustomView == null) {
                return;
            } else {
                // Hide the custom view.
                mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // Remove the custom view from its container.
                mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
                mCustomView = null;
                mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
                // Show the content view.
                mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setContentView(mContentView);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mCustomViewContainer != null)
            mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
        else if (myWebView.canGoBack())
            myWebView.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

This is my code 2 :

```
package inducesmile.com.playvideoinandroid;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MyWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = null;
    private View mCustomView;
    private RelativeLayout mContentView;
    private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://murid.gkdi.org/test/in.html");


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }
            mContentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
            mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewContainer = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
            mCustomViewContainer.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
            mCustomViewContainer.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
            view.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
            mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
            mCustomView = view;
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1)
        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            if (mCustomView == null) {
                return;
            } else {
                // Hide the custom view.
                mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // Remove the custom view from its container.
                mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
                mCustomView = null;
                mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
                // Show the content view.
                mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setContentView(mContentView);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mCustomViewContainer != null)
            mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
        else if (myWebView.canGoBack())
            myWebView.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have something weird in your code where you are selecting layer type. First you check according to SDK version, and then ignore that and set the layer to software. Also check logcat if you have any messages there

Comment: use this:
https://github.com/firozanawar/Android-YouTube-Player

Answer (score 1):

use video api of youtube to play youtube videos in android app

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference